# How to override a docker env if when it is used by another env?

Tags: docker

Is there any way to have an environment variable use another in a Dockerfile, in a way that I can override them at `docker run` time?

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM docker.ouroath.com:4443/containers/ylinux7-buildtools
ENV VARX foo
ENV VARY ${VARX}bar
CMD env

$ docker build -t envtest
...

$ docker run envtest
VARY=foobar
VARX=foo


$ docker run -e VARX=123 envtest
VARY=foobar
VARX=123
```

How can I change only X=123 and get Y=123bar to implement something like shortvar pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Everything in a Dockerfile (except the `CMD`) is fully evaluated and expanded when the image is built.  So in this setup, the variable `Y` always has the value when the `ENV` statement was executed, even if you change parts of the expression later when the image is run.

You can get around this with an entrypoint wrapper script.  For example:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# Give the variable Y a computed value, if it's not already set.
if [ -z "$VARY" ]; then
  export VARY="${VARX}bar"
fi

# Run the main container command.
exec "$@"
```

```bash
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV VARX=foo
# do not set VARY here
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD env
```

The `ENTRYPOINT` will run at container startup, getting passed the `CMD` as arguments.  This does the first-time setup (here setting the environment variable) and then the last line runs the `CMD` (or whatever you override it with running the container).

```bash
docker build -t envtest .

docker run --rm envtest | grep VAR
# VARX=foo
# VARY=foobar

docker run --rm -e VARX=quux envtest | grep VAR
# VARX=quux
# VARY=quuxbar

docker run --rm -e VARY=quux envtest | grep VAR
# VARX=foo
# VARY=quux

docker run --rm envtest sh -c 'echo hello $VARY'
# hello foobar
```